# div under div in two-column layout

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm making a basic citation generator mockup with two columns: one for the list of already-generated citations, and one with a form to create a new one. Each element is in a div. Because the form is shorter in height than the citation list, I'm putting an example image underneath that could be replaced with an advertisment.

However, despite placing the first column (citation list) and second (form and ad) in different divs, the ad stays underneath the citation list:

```css
#container {
  text-align: center;
}

#header {
  margin-bottom: 3em;
  margin-top: 2em;
}

#header h3 {
  color: darkgrey;
  font-size: 1em;
}

#citationList {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 15%;
  width: 30%;
}

#citationList #citations {
  border: 1px solid darkgrey;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-top: 1.5em;
}

#creationForm {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 15%;
  width: 30%
}

#creationForm form {
  border: 1px solid darkgrey;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-top: 1.5em;
}

#creationForm form label {
  float: left;
}

#creationForm form input .textBox {
  float: right;
}

#adSpace {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="header">
      <h1>Citation Generator</h1>
      <h3>it's totally amazing</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      <div id="citationList">
        <h4>Your Citations</h4>
        <ul id="citations">
          <li>Citations are listed here</li>
          <li>This can be however long</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      <div id="creationForm">
        <h4>Create a Citation</h4>
        <form>
          <!-- Author -->
          <label for="someInput">Some input:</label>
          <input id="someInput" type="text" class="textBox" />
          <label for="moreInput">More input:</label>
          <input id="moreInput" type="text" class="textBox" />
          <label for="evenMoreInput">Even more input:</label>
          <input id="evenMoreInput" type="text" class="textBox" />
          <label for="muchMoreInput">Much more input:</label>
          <input id="muchMoreInput" type="text" class="textBox" />
      </div>
      <div id="adSpace">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300.jpg?text=Placeholder+Advertisment" />
        <p>Advertisment</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `clear:both;` as shown below

```
#adSpace {
    float: right;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: The clear property is directly related to floats. If the element can fit horizontally in the space next to another element which is floated, it will. Unless you apply clear to that element in the same direction as the float. Then the element will move down below the floated element. Read more https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/clear/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected CSS and HTML.

```css
#container {
  text-align: center;
}

#header {
  margin-bottom: 3em;
  margin-top: 2em;
}

#header h3 {
  color: darkgrey;
  font-size: 1em;
}
.contentContainer {
  width:1200px;
  margin:0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
#citationList {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

#citationList #citations {
  border: 1px solid darkgrey;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-top: 1.5em;
}

#creationForm {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  width: 100%
}

#creationForm form {
  border: 1px solid darkgrey;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-top: 1.5em;
}
.row {
 margin:10px -15px;
}
#creationForm form label {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
}

#creationForm form input.textBox {
  float: left;
}

#adSpace {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<html>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="header">
      <h1>Citation Generator</h1>
      <h3>it's totally amazing</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="contentContainer">
     <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
       <div id="citationList">
         <h4>Your Citations</h4>
         <ul id="citations">
           Looks like you don't have any citations made yet!
         </ul>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
       <div id="creationForm">
         <h4>Create a Citation</h4>
         <form>
           <!-- Author -->
           <div class="row">
            <label for="authorFirst">Author's first name:</label>
            <input id="authorFirst" type="text" class="textBox" />
           </div>
           <div class="row">
            <label for="authorLast">Author's last name:</label>
            <input id="authorLast" type="text" class="textBox" />
           </div>
           <br />
           <!-- Website -->
           <div class="row">
            <label for="pageTitle">Title of page/article:</label>
            <input id="pageTitle" type="text" class="textBox" />
        </div>
           <div class="row">
            <label for="siteTitle">Title of website:</label>
            <input id="siteTitle" type="text" class="textBox" />
        </div>
           <br />
           <!-- Dates -->
           <div class="row">
            <label for="datePublished">Date published:</label>
            <input id="datePublished" type="text" class="textBox" />
        </div>
           <div class="row">
            <label for="dateAccessed">Date accessed:</label>
            <input id="dateAccessed" type="text" class="textBox" />
        </div>
         </form>
       </div>
       <div id="adSpace">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300.jpg?text=Placeholder+Advertisment" />
         <p>Advertisment</p>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```